# How to write a CloudFormation template file for multiple existing resources for one-click deployment

Tags: aws-cloudformation, aws-cdk, aws-sam

I'm new to AWS CloudFormation stack deployment and I'm looking for resources to help me able to make a one-click deploy functionality on my company's website. The resources (a single API Gateway REST API and with two Lambda functions of which one is an authorizer) are already set up in our AWS account, but I'm looking for the quickest and most effective way to generate the CloudFormation template file from these resources that have already been set up.

I'm aware that the SAM YAML file for the Lambdas can be obtained from the Lambda console itself (under the Export dropdown). For the API Gateway REST API, the closest thing I can find is the Swagger file that can be generated under Stages. However I'm not sure if it's of any help in terms of generating the final YAML (or JSON) template file which I need to upload to CloudFormation to set up the stack.

Looking for directions, any insights would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to export a full CloudFormation template from any resources in AWS, especially from multiple resources together.

You can combine different exports, such as the swagger export from the REST API, and include it in your template but you will have to combine them yourself.

You can use the template designer from AWS and search for tutorials/examples online to help you out, but the full template, you'll have to create yourself.